# Compile golang for AirOS

Tags: go

I want to compile a simple application written in GO to run on my Ubiquiti Nanostation running AirOS 6.0.4. I tried some combination of OS + ARCH involving Linux + mips but had no luck. Is this possible to do? If so, what do I have to do.

Comment: Exactly what os/arch combinations did you use, and what kind of errors did you get when it "didn't work"?

Comment: I've used every mips* + Linux combination. I'll post specific errors tomorrow since I have no access to the device right now.

Comment: turns out that it's running out of memory `fatal error: runtime: out of memory` wich is odd because the program had just a print function. Seems that that's how far I'm going to get on this experiment.

Comment: Seems so. Sorry I couldn't help, the nanostation is probably running right on the edge with it's default software or some such.

Comment: thanks for your help :+1:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating GO from the version I was running (1.9) to 1.10 did the trick. The proper combination of OS/ARCH is linux/mips but for some reason the I kept getting the `out of memory` error until I updated.

After compiling the application I also recommend to use this https://blog.filippo.io/shrink-your-go-binaries-with-this-one-weird-trick/ information to reduce the executable size as the free space on the Ubiquiti Nanostations is not really much.